# I need label expression in python to stack labels for points present at same geometry

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, python-parser

I have a data set that has stacked points. I need to display the labels as one.  The dataset has locations that only have 1 point and some that have 2 or 3 stacked points. I’d also like to be able to change the color of the number on the background based upon a threshold exceedance of the value in the fourth row [GeoMean]. I’m thinking some kind of arcpy script within the label manager is the way to go.

[image]
This is how I want

[image]
This is how I am getting

[image]
This is VBScript I am using but I need in python.

**[LocationID] only needs to be displayed once for the stacked points while [MediumSub], [n] and [GeoMean] need to be displayed for each stacked point.**

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be showing screen shots from ArcMap. I don't believe what you are asking is possible and the expression would need to do some sort of spatial analysis to determine if a point is part of a stack of points.

This might be something you could achieve in an ArcGIS Pro Pop-up using Arcade but then that's not a label, nor the same software.

I think your solution here is to pre-process your dataset so that there is only 1 point (when there was a stack of points) and ensure all the information you require to create the label is passed over in appropriate fields. You would then build your label from that.

Comment: I have to present data in layers of different points, All points are stacked over each other at same location and giving different labels. I just want to stack them all in single label. I think its possible and working on it, as soon as as I'll find something, I'll share with you.